# multiple statements inside textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange method?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitextfield

I want all my textfields to react in real time, I want them all to capture the characters being typed in and do something accordingly, however it seems i can't get two statements to act in harmony inside a `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method. here is the code I am attempting to complete:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        let invalidCharacters = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890_").invertedSet

        if textField == usernameTxt || textField == passwordTxt || textField == confirmTxt  {

            if let range = string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(invalidCharacters, options: nil, range:Range<String.Index>(start: string.startIndex, end: string.endIndex)) {

                println("error")

                return false
            }
            return true

        }; if range.length + range.location > count(usernameTxt.text) {


          return false

        }else {

        let NewLength = count(usernameTxt.text) + count(string) - range.length

        return NewLength <= 5

        }
    return true
    }
```

the first statement of the code works when it is alone in the func, however when i try to add the second statement, I just get the following error :

[image]

why so? and how should i achieve this properly?

and I have this last method to implement within the function that will check in real time if the username has already been taken:

```
var isTaken: Bool = false

         var query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
        query.whereKey("username", equalTo: usernameTxt.text)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) in
            if error == nil {
                if (objects!.count > 0){
                    isTaken = true
                    let myAlert = SCLAlertView().showError("Woah There", subTitle: "username \(textField.text) is already taken", closeButtonTitle: "Got It")
                    myAlert.alertview.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0)
                    myAlert.alertview.circleBG.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0)
                    myAlert.alertview.labelTitle.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                    myAlert.alertview.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0).CGColor
                    myAlert.alertview.viewText.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                    myAlert.alertview.viewText.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0)

                } else {
                    println("Username is available. ")
                }
            } else {
                println("error")
            }
        }
```

Comment: what happens when you remove the second "return true" that's right in the middle of your method? Seemis like perhaps that's cutting off the method before it has time to get to the second if/then statement perhaps          return false
            }
            return true

        }; if range.length + range.location > count(usernameTxt.text) {   this return true statment, not the bottom one

Comment: when i separate the middle return true statements it has no effects to the last one, probably because the middle return true statement is tied to the first statement only, not the whole function.

Comment: Oh yeah, nvm, I see what you are doing, one sec

Comment: yeah @Larcerax I just want a way to do this properly

Comment: First off, the last if/then statement wont allow the last "return true " to execute EVER, this is because you are returning  "  return NewLength <= 5" in your else statement, now, what is is that you are trying to do here, what's the purpose of this method, meaning why are you returning "NewLength <= 5", this function isn't a Number return function, it returns either true or false, and this "NewLength <= 5" is saying, "return false if NewLength is greater than 5, and true if it's less than 5", is this what you wanted?

Comment: I'm just trying to wrap my head around the purpose and I can almost guarantee we can figure this out in like 10 minutes, just say explicitly what you are trying to do with this function

Comment: ok well the first statement basically prevents the use of any characters in the text field out side that custom character set i have, the second statement will send a message to the user when they have gone over the character limit. thats all @Larcerax

Comment: perfect, okay, give me a second

Comment: the first statement is perfect, I'm just trying to intergrate the second one properly @Larcerax

Comment: Do you have more textfields than the three textfields in the method, I see username, confirm, and password

Comment: yes but the other one is an email textfield, that doesn't need regulating really, but i just want to get a character limit for the username textfield @Larcerax

Comment: I'm asking because it seems that this:        return false
            }
            return true

        };  will never allow the username,confirm, and password fields to go only to the next if/then statment after the semi colon, this is part of the problem, you see the first if /then passes everything through EXCEPT for the emailfield, and then if the NEXT if/then is NOT true, then you return TRUE which TO ME means the function is over, unless a "semi colon" in swift means to keep executing the code even when a "return" statement has been called

Comment: i mean a semicolon just separates statements. if i was able to combine the statements then i would've did so, but that would be trouble some @Larcerax

Comment: and then this "if range.length + range.location > count(usernameTxt.text) {" is only suppose to work o the "usernameTxt.text" right?

Comment: check my answer out, I dont' care if I get downvoted, this shoudl work, I don't do swift but this does compile and should capture the usernametext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this should work, revamped to capture what we were talking about in the comments above:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let invalidCharacters = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890_").invertedSet

    if textField == usernameTxt || textField == passwordTxt || textField == confirmTxt {
        if let range = string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(invalidCharacters, options: nil, range:Range<String.Index>(start: string.startIndex, end: string.endIndex)) {
            println("error")
            return false
        }
        if textField == usernameTxt {
            if range.length + range.location > count(usernameTxt.text) {
                return false
            } else {
                let NewLength = count(usernameTxt.text) + count(string) - range.length
                return NewLength <= 5
            }
        }
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

This is a start, but we will have to keep working on this, however, this should capture the return statements in the correct order given what you want. The first if/then will filter out the email field and return false, the second if/then will return false if it is true, then we check the username field alone, we do work on the user name field and return true or false based on the username field, if THIS isn't the username field, we return true.

Now, as for the username portion, what are you trying to accomplish there, just state it, I don't want to think through this logic, once I know this then we can flesh out any problems with the username-specific if/then statement, what's the goal? AND, what takes priority for the username field, is it the character check for the username field that takes priority or is it the next username check? I'm asking because this method will terminate if the username field is TRUE for the second if/then statement of this function and it will never reach the second if/then function for the username alone.

Second part of your question, probably the better way to do this is this way, user the delegate function from UITextFieldDelegate to intercept the "RETURN KEY" press form the user when they try to move to the next field, this will intercept this event and CHECK to make sure the username isn't taken:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool{
    if (textField === usernameTxt) {
        var isTaken: Bool = false
        var query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
        query.whereKey("username", equalTo: usernameTxt.text)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) in
            if error == nil {
                if (objects!.count > 0){
                    isTaken = true
                    let myAlert = SCLAlertView().showError("Woah There", subTitle: "username \(textField.text) is already taken", closeButtonTitle: "Got It")
                    myAlert.alertview.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0)
                    myAlert.alertview.circleBG.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0)
                    myAlert.alertview.labelTitle.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                    myAlert.alertview.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0).CGColor
                    myAlert.alertview.viewText.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                    myAlert.alertview.viewText.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0)
                } else {
                    println("Username is available. ")
                }
            } else {
                println("error")
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Here's the answer to your last question, well this should be the answer, this is to make sure you are hitting the username field TWO times before the function returns:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField == emailTxt {
        return true
    } else {
        let invalidCharacters = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890_").invertedSet
        let range2 = range
        if textField == usernameTxt || textField == passwordTxt || textField == confirmTxt {
            if let range = string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(invalidCharacters, options: nil, range:Range<String.Index>(start: string.startIndex, end: string.endIndex)) {
                println("error")
                if textField == usernameTxt {
                    if range2.length + range2.location > count(usernameTxt.text) {
                        return false
                    } else {
                        let NewLength = count(usernameTxt.text) + count(string) - range2.length
                        return NewLength <= 5
                    }
                }
                return false
            }
            if textField == usernameTxt {
                if range.length + range.location > count(usernameTxt.text) {
                    return false
                } else {
                    let NewLength = count(usernameTxt.text) + count(string) - range.length
                    return NewLength <= 5
                }
            }
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

You see, the first if/then captures the fields you want, the second if/then captures the ones with bad chcaraters, the third one captures the username field and RETURNS if it's true or false, so this is the problem with the first solution I posted above this one, you will want to use the username length check TWO times in this method and the username field will only be exposed to this length check a single time in this function. So, I'm duplicating the IF/THEN check for the text length of the username, but that's fine, it should work anyway. It would be BEST if you had like another "BOOL return FUNCTION" that was outside this method that checked the length of the username and then returned true or false, but this will work too with code duplication of 1 if/then statement.

Comment: now while we are on the topic here i have one more inquiry, i want to add one more statement/method in that will check if the username entered in the `usernameTxt` textfield has already been taken, check updated question

Comment: sure, k, one sec, oh very good, I love Parse, let me look at this really quick

Comment: Okay, so one thing you want to be careful of is this: if you place this CHECK IF USERNAME IS TAKEN in the method above, then you will be querying the Parse server non-stop while the person is typing, is this what you want? that's a hell of a lot of server requests

Comment: So, look at my answer again, Mike, this will give you an idea of how to do this Parse query ONLY at the end when the user pressed the RETURN key of the username field, then it wil pop and alert view, check my answer in one sec

Comment: you know what you are right, i'll probably implement that later down the line, so one last thing, in the second statement where the characters are limited, i want to send an alert when the user attempts to go over the limit, i tried inputting the `println("error")` but it would not show in the console. is it possible?

Comment: Oh wait up, let me see what you wrote, one sec

Comment: Yes, this is also possible, this is where it gets complicated, it's code duplication, but it doesn't matter, I'll show you one sec

Comment: haha, the crazy thing is thats the exact code i already have, i just wanted to do it in real time instead of intercepting the return key because what if they fill out all the other textfields first then the username textfield last, they may go straight to the sign up button i have

Comment: yep, I'm posting it now, this is NOT the best solution because it duplicates code, but you'll see

Comment: there we go, try that out, Mike, I made a variable that points to the method's range variable named "range2" otherwise it won't find the NEW range variable you declared. so this should compile fine

Comment: And let me know if this totally sucks, I don't know if we got the range variable right, but I think we did

Comment: hey, since you said you love parse, can i interest you in a very quick chat? i have about 2 questions on file transfer in parse

Comment: start the chat, I'll be able to jump in and talk a little bit later, I'm coding a HUGE parse app right now myself, and it's almost done, give me like 1-2 hours

Comment: here's the chat, please let respond when you are ready! http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/87213/parse-aws-s3-and-swift

Comment: you available in the chat?